# Is there some good method for dividing the polygon

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

The task is to recognize a specific object in an image and enclose it in a rectangle with the minimum area. However, when objects are adjacent, as shown in the images below, they are judged to be one outline and a very large rectangle is created. In this case, can we divide it into appropriate rectangles?

[image]

[image]

How to split a polygonal object into minimum number of rectangles

Answer (score 0):

To guide you in some direction

1. find corner points (`corners`) of your polygon
2. find `pairs_h` of points that are (approximately?) on a horizontal line
3. find `pairs_v` of points that are (approximately?) on a vertical line
4. find `rectangles` by combining `pairs_h` with `pairs_v` by checking if they share (approximately?) single points